# Checking and displaying values of array compared to another array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

One data set is an object of arrays of ids and another is an object of arrays of ids and names. What I'd like to do is check if the ids from the first data exist in the second data set and if they do then display the names.

This is what is being called by the component, which works correctly:

```
<td>Genre</td>
<td>{this.matchGenres(this.props.movie.genre_ids, this.props.genres)}</td>
```

And this is the function that I can't get to work:

```
matchGenres = (genres, genreList) => {

    genres.forEach((genre) => {
      genreList.filter((list) => {
         return list.id === genre;
      }).map((newList) => {
         return newList.name;
      });
    });

  }
```

It looks like the operation performs correctly and returns the right names when I console.log it! But! its not showing up in the component on render.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const genres = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Jazz Music"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Something"
}];

const genreList = [1, 10, 100];

matchGenres = (genres, genreList) => genres
  .filter(genre => genreList.includes(genre.id))
  .map(genre => genre.name);

const matchedGenres = matchGenres(genres, genreList);

console.log(matchedGenres);
```

Answer (score 1):

> But! its not showing up in the component on render.

Its because your function doesn't return anything. You return inside `filter` and `map` and your function does not return anything. Also note that `forEach` always return `undefined`

You just need a minor change. Try this

```js
let genres = ["1", "2", "3"];
let genreList = [{
  id: "2",
  name: "Two"
}, {
  id: "32",
  name: "Three"
}]

matchGenres = (genres, genreList) => {

  return genreList.filter((list) => {
    // findIndex return array index if found else return -1 if not found
    return genres.findIndex(genere => genere === list.id) > -1;
  }).map(list => list.name);

}

console.log(matchGenres(genres, genreList));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that ended up working:

```
if (genreList.length !== 0) {
  return genres.map(genre => genreList.find(list => list.id === genre)).map((newList) => newList.name) + ',';
}
```

For some reason the value of GenreList, which is an array, was showing up as empty for the first couple times the function is call. Thats another problem I'll have to look at but the if statement solves for it for the time being.

Comment: The Answer box isn't really for asking follow up questions. Any Answer on this thread must answer the Question, not a question in an Answer. Please visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27477764)

Comment: @PMerlet There's an actual answer in this post. It should not be deleted due to the last sentence. If anything, it can be edited out.